# Implementation of concurrency safe custom data type in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency

I want to implement following data-type

```
public class MyType
{
    void Set(int i);
    void AddHandler(int i, Action action);
}
```

Semantics are as follows.

1. Both methods must be concurrency safe.
2. Maximum value of 'i' is known and is relatively low (~100).
3. Trying to set i more than once should fail.
4. Calling set with value i should call all handlers registered for that i.
5. AddHandler registers new handler for given i. If i is already set, action is immediately called.

For example, consider the following sequence

```
Set(1)
Set(2)
AddHandler(3, f1)
AddHandler(3, f2)
Set(1)            // Fails, 1 is already set
AddHandler(2, g)  // g is called as 2 is already set
Set(3)            // f1, f2 are called
AddHandler(3, h)  // h is called as 3 is now set
```

Goal is to minimize allocations needed to be done for each method call. Here is code for my attempt to implement it.

```
public class MyType
{
    const int N = 10;
    static readonly Action[] s_emptyHandler = new Action[0];

    readonly bool[] m_vars = new bool[N];
    readonly List<Action>[] m_handlers = new List<Action>[N];

    public void Set(int i)
    {
        Action[] handlers;

        lock (this)
        {
            if (m_vars[i]) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            m_vars[i] = true;
            handlers = m_handlers[i] != null ? m_handlers[i].ToArray() : s_emptyHandler;
        }

        foreach (var action in handlers)
            action();
    }

    public void AddHandler(int i, Action action)
    {
        var done = false;

        lock (this)
        {
            if (m_vars[i])
                done = true;
            else
            {
                if(m_handlers[i] == null)
                    m_handlers[i] = new List<Action>();

                m_handlers[i].Add(action);
            }
        }

        if (done)
            action();
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your code, where you tried to do it

Comment: should be as simple as `lock (myDictionary) { ... }` - just remember to not call the actions inside the lock - instead get out the current observers and call them afterwards - if you want it a bit more fancy use the concurrent collection stuff

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. Regarding the second comment, yes I have something similar in mind. But that requires me to snapshot current set of handlers. Is there any concurrent collection that you have in mind that would help avoid it?

Comment: What scalability requirements do you have? This is trivial if you can use a global lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking array snapshot at every `Set` method is ineffective. From the other side, since you need additional synchronization, using `BlockingCollection` doesn't make sense. For your case, some immutable collection would fit better.
There are even simple method taking advantage of the fact that you are only adding handlers. We can use an explicit array with count field pair instead of a list class, so all we need to do inside the `Set` method is to take array reference and count value inside the protected block. Then we can safely iterate the array up to count and invoke the handlers. Here is a code using the approach described:

```
public class MyType
{
    struct Entry
    {
        public bool IsSet;
        public int HandlerCount;
        public Action[] HandlerList;
        public void Add(Action handler)
        {
            if (HandlerList == null) HandlerList = new Action[4];
            else if (HandlerList.Length == HandlerCount) Array.Resize(ref HandlerList, 2 * HandlerCount);
            HandlerList[HandlerCount++] = handler;
        }
    }
    const int N = 10;
    readonly Entry[] entries = new Entry[N];
    readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public void Set(int index)
    {
        int handlerCount;
        Action[] handlerList;
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            if (entries[index].IsSet) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            entries[index].IsSet = true;
            handlerCount = entries[index].HandlerCount;
            handlerList = entries[index].HandlerList;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < handlerCount; i++)
            handlerList[i]();
    }
    public void AddHandler(int index, Action handler)
    {
        if (handler == null) throw new ArgumentException("handler");
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            entries[index].Add(handler);
            if (!entries[index].IsSet) return;
        }
        handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it safe to enumerate array while it is being resized? Seems likely but just wanted to confirm

Comment: Absolutely. Resize is a helper method that creates a new array, copies the existing and safely replaces the old array reference passed - as you may see here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyType
    {
        private HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
        private Dictionary<int, BlockingCollection<Action>> actions = new Dictionary<int, BlockingCollection<Action>>();

        private void ExecuteActions(BlockingCollection<Action> toExecute)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!toExecute.IsCompleted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Action action = toExecute.Take();
                        action();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            });
        }

        public void Set(int i)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (!set.Contains(i))
                {
                    set.Add(i);

                    BlockingCollection<Action> toExecute;
                    if (!actions.TryGetValue(i, out toExecute))
                    {
                        actions[i] = toExecute = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
                    }

                    ExecuteActions(toExecute);
                }
            }
        }


        public void AddHandler(int i, Action action)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                BlockingCollection<Action> toExecute;
                if (!actions.TryGetValue(i, out toExecute))
                {
                    actions[i] = toExecute = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
                }

                toExecute.Add(action);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see the update. This approach (as well as one I can think of) requires taking array snapshots which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: If we do not want to execute handlers inside the lock (for obvious reasons), then you would need to clone the list 'toExecute' so that you can walk over it outside the lock.

Comment: You can use `BlockingCollection` - see updated answer

Comment: Thanks again! I liked use of blocking-collection. BTW your code doesn't exactly follow specifications (sorry if they were ambiguous).  If we make calls Set(a), Set(b), AddHandler(a, action) in order. We still want action to be called immediately. I am aware that it can be easily modified to meet the requirements, just pointing out so that there is no confusion!

Comment: Which part is it not following exactly??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91817/discussion-between-petar-ivanov-and-suyog).